# Implementation of an asynchronous TCP/UDP server

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking

I am trying to implement a TCP/UDP server so all I have to do is something like this:

```
var server = new Server(Type.UDP, "127.0.0.1", 8888);
server.OnDataRecieved += Datahandler;
server.Start();
```

I have tried to make it perform as fast as possible by using Asynchronous calls where possible.

I basically would like to know if there is anything missing/any changes that people would recommend (and why). It is not finished yet as I need to handle exceptions better etc...

TODO: I need to complete the signature of the events to make them more meaningful, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace SBlackler.Networking
{
public sealed class HighPerformanceServer
{
    private Int32 _currentConnections = 0;
    Socket listener;
    EndPoint ipeSender;


    #region "Properties"

    public Int32 Port { get; set; }
    public Int32 CurrentConnections { get { return _currentConnections; } }
    public Int32 MaxQueuedConnections { get; set; }
    public IPEndPoint Endpoint { get; set; }
    public ServerType Type { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region "Constructors"

    private HighPerformanceServer()
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public HighPerformanceServer(ServerType type, String IpAddress)
    {
        Init(type, IpAddress, 28930);
    }

    public HighPerformanceServer(ServerType type, String IpAddress, Int32 Port)
    {
        Init(type, IpAddress, Port);
    }

    private void Init(ServerType server, String IpAddress, Int32 Port)
    {
        IPAddress ip;
        // Check the IpAddress to make sure that it is valid
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(IpAddress) && IPAddress.TryParse(IpAddress, out ip))
        {
            this.Endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, Port);
            // Make sure that the port is greater than 100 as not to conflict with any other programs
            if (Port < 100)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The argument 'Port' is not valid. Please select a value greater than 100.");
            }
            else
            {
                this.Port = Port;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The argument 'IpAddress' is not valid");
        }
        // We never want a ServerType of None, but we include it as it is recommended by FXCop.
        if (server != ServerType.None)
        {
            this.Type = server;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The argument 'ServerType' is not valid");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region "Events"

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnServerStart;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnServerStarted;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnServerStopping;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnServerStoped;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnClientConnected;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnClientDisconnecting;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnClientDisconnected;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnDataReceived;

    #endregion

    public void Start()
    {
        // Tell anything that is listening that we have starting to work
        if (OnServerStart != null)
        {
            OnServerStart(this, null);
        }

        // Get either a TCP or UDP socket depending on what we specified when we created the class
        listener = GetCorrectSocket();

        if (listener != null)
        {
            // Bind the socket to the endpoint
            listener.Bind(this.Endpoint);

            // TODO :: Add throttleling (using SEMAPHORE's)

            if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP)
            {
                // Start listening to the socket, accepting any backlog
                listener.Listen(this.MaxQueuedConnections);

                // Use the BeginAccept to accept new clients
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ClientConnected), listener);
            }
            else if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP)
            {
                // So we can buffer and store information, create a new information class
                SocketConnectionInfo connection = new SocketConnectionInfo();
                connection.Buffer = new byte[SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize];
                connection.Socket = listener;
                // Setup the IPEndpoint
                ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.Port);
                // Start recieving from the client
                listener.BeginReceiveFrom(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ipeSender, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
            }

            // Tell anything that is listening that we have started to work
            if (OnServerStarted != null)
            {
                OnServerStarted(this, null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // There was an error creating the correct socket
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not create the correct sever socket type.");
        }
    }

    internal Socket GetCorrectSocket()
    {
        if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP)
        {
            return new Socket(this.Endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }
        else if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP)
        {
            return new Socket(this.Endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (OnServerStopping != null)
        {
            OnServerStopping(this, null);
        }

        if (OnServerStoped != null)
        {
            OnServerStoped(this, null);
        }
    }

    internal void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // Increment our ConcurrentConnections counter
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _currentConnections);

        // So we can buffer and store information, create a new information class
        SocketConnectionInfo connection = new SocketConnectionInfo();
        connection.Buffer = new byte[SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize];

        // We want to end the async event as soon as possible
        Socket asyncListener = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        Socket asyncClient = asyncListener.EndAccept(asyncResult);

        // Set the SocketConnectionInformations socket to the current client
        connection.Socket = asyncClient;

        // Tell anyone that's listening that we have a new client connected
        if (OnClientConnected != null)
        {
            OnClientConnected(this, null);
        }

        // TODO :: Add throttleling (using SEMAPHORE's)

        // Begin recieving the data from the client
        if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP)
        {
            asyncClient.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
        }
        else if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP)
        {
            asyncClient.BeginReceiveFrom(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ipeSender, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
        }
        // Now we have begun recieving data from this client,
        // we can now accept a new client
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ClientConnected), listener);
    }

    internal void DataReceived(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketConnectionInfo connection = (SocketConnectionInfo)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            Int32 bytesRead;
            // End the correct async process
            if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP)
            {
                bytesRead = connection.Socket.EndReceiveFrom(asyncResult, ref ipeSender);
            }
            else if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP)
            {
                bytesRead = connection.Socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            }
            else
            {
                bytesRead = 0;
            }
            // Increment the counter of BytesRead
            connection.BytesRead += bytesRead;
            // Check to see whether the socket is connected or not...
            if (IsSocketConnected(connection.Socket))
            {
                // If we have read no more bytes, raise the data received event
                if (bytesRead == 0 || (bytesRead > 0 && bytesRead < SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = connection.Buffer;
                    Int32 totalBytesRead = connection.BytesRead;
                    // Setup the connection info again ready for another packet
                    connection = new SocketConnectionInfo();
                    connection.Buffer = new byte[SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize];
                    connection.Socket = ((SocketConnectionInfo)asyncResult.AsyncState).Socket;
                    // Fire off the receive event as quickly as possible, then we can process the data...
                    if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP)
                    {
                        connection.Socket.BeginReceiveFrom(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ipeSender, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
                    }
                    else if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP)
                    {
                        connection.Socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
                    }
                    // Remove any extra data
                    if (totalBytesRead < buffer.Length)
                    {
                        Array.Resize<Byte>(ref buffer, totalBytesRead);
                    }
                    // Now raise the event, sender will contain the buffer for now
                    if (OnDataReceived != null)
                    {
                        OnDataReceived(buffer, null);
                    }
                    buffer = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Resize the array ready for the next chunk of data
                    Array.Resize<Byte>(ref connection.Buffer, connection.Buffer.Length + SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize);
                    // Fire off the receive event again, with the bigger buffer
                    if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP)
                    {
                        connection.Socket.BeginReceiveFrom(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ipeSender, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
                    }
                    else if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP)
                    {
                        connection.Socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), connection);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(connection.BytesRead > 0)
            {
                // We still have data
                Array.Resize<Byte>(ref connection.Buffer, connection.BytesRead);
                // call the event
                if (OnDataReceived != null)
                {
                    OnDataReceived(connection.Buffer, null);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    internal bool IsSocketConnected(Socket socket)
    {
        return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
    }

    internal void DisconnectClient(SocketConnectionInfo connection)
    {
        if (OnClientDisconnecting != null)
        {
            OnClientDisconnecting(this, null);
        }
        connection.Socket.BeginDisconnect(true, new AsyncCallback(ClientDisconnected), connection);
    }

    internal void ClientDisconnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        SocketConnectionInfo sci = (SocketConnectionInfo)asyncResult;
        sci.Socket.EndDisconnect(asyncResult);
        if (OnClientDisconnected != null)
        {
            OnClientDisconnected(this, null);
        }
    }
}

public class SocketConnectionInfo
{
    public const Int32 BufferSize = 1048576;
    public Socket Socket;
    public byte[] Buffer;
    public Int32 BytesRead { get; set; }
}


public enum ServerType
{
    None = 0,
    TCP = 1,
    UDP = 2
}
}
```

Comment: Define "correct."  It could mean any number of different things.

Comment: @JeffMercado, ie have I missed something or is there a best practise for a certain section of code that I am not aware (eg, receiving a connection)

Comment: How to distinguish between multiple connected clients (requesting in parallel) when I receive the OnDataRecieved event? Maybe I haven't fully understand whats going on or this code is for one connected Client only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a quick glance, there are a couple minor things I noticed regarding how you handle your events:

- You are passing null event args.  I would instead use EventArgs.Empty, as callers will typically assume the EventArgs object they get from the event handler will be non-null.
- You are using Interlocked.Increment on your connection counter, suggesting you are going to be using this in multi-threaded code.

As such, you should note that

```
if (OnClientConnected!= null)
{
   OnClientConnected (this, null);
}
```

is not thread-safe.  Instead, you will want to do something more like the following:

```
var  evt = OnClientConnected;
if (evt != null)
{
   evt (this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I would suggest converting all your internal members to private, unless there is a specific need for other classes to access them, which seems unlikely, given their content.

Additionally, if SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize is >= 0, then

```
if (bytesRead == 0 || (bytesRead > 0 && bytesRead < SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize))
```

can be converted to

```
if (bytesRead < SocketConnectionInfo.BufferSize)
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up about `EventArgs.Empty` didn't know that it existed.

Comment: @Dan Lyons - good suggestion on the private members, but isn't setting the evt var = OnClientConnection merely creating a pointer to the same object?  How is this more thread safe?

Comment: Thankfully, Eric Lippert has answered that one for me :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx

Comment: @Aerik, good question. It's a legal optimization according to ECMA, but "all of Microsoft's JIT compilers respect the invariant of not introducing new reads to heap memory and therefore, caching a reference in a local variable ensures that the heap reference is accessed only once" (from CLR via C#, page 264-265). That means that it's thread safe on Microsoft implementations, and I guess that Mono would recognize the [very common] pattern to apply the same functionality.

Comment: There's more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664046/allowed-c-sharp-compiler-optimization-on-local-variables-and-refetching-value-fr where it's noted that the ECMA specification differs from what .NET Framework 2.0 does.

Answer (score 7):

1, Create (at least) two classes. One for UDP and one for TCP. It would omit lots of code like this:

```
if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP) {
    ...
} else if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP) {
    ...
}
```

Maybe a common abstract parent class and a factory are also required.

2, Anyway, in the following snippet the last `else` branch should throw an exception:

```
if (this.Type == ServerType.TCP) {
    ...
} else if (this.Type == ServerType.UDP) {
    ...
} else {
    return null;
}
```

I don't think that there is any state when `Type != TCP` and `Type != UDP` too.